# spring data redis Failed to deserialize object type; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: spring-data, jedis, spring-data-redis

I am using spring-data-redis 1.1.0 and jedis 2.1.0.

When i deploy my code to Karaf, i'am getting the below exception:

`Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; 
nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to deserialize object type; 
nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`

It is working when my i am running JUnit.

Below is my redisTemplate.

`<bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate">`

Comment: can you please provide a little more information on what class can actually not be found. and what your setup looks like. btw sd-redis current version is 1.4.0.RELEASE.

Comment: I resolved the above using BeanUtils, but i am now getting org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot deserialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 77686174

Comment: How was this issue solved? i am getting the same issue..